# Back to line in a doc.DXL?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula, readxl

I am using IBM Domino Designer 9.0 and i have a problem with the DXL .
How to return to line in a doc.DXL (that I created)?
I tried with \ n and <\ br> but it does not work .
So plz some help .

```
Code Button : 

Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim Stream As NotesStream
    Set Stream=Session.CreateStream
    f=Freefile
    fichier="d:\"+Masque.FieldGetText("nom")+".dxl"
    Open fichier For Output As #f
    Stream.Open(fichier)

    Call Stream.WriteText(|..............................>|)
.........................
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datamodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datetime dst="true">|+Now+|</datetime>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</datamodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<designmodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<datetime dst="true">|+Now+|</datetime>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</designmodified>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</databaseinfo>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|<form name="|+Masque.FieldGetText("nom")+|" nocompose="true" publicaccess="false" designerversion="8.5.3" recalc="true" renderpassthrough="true">|)
    ...........
Call Stream.WriteText(|<text>test</text>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</item>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</form>|)
    Call Stream.WriteText(|</database>|)
    Stream.Close

End Sub
```

The output  :
............................
   13/04/2019 14:52:56    13/04/2019 14:52:56          Option Public        Dim Session As NotesSession   Dim curDb As NotesDatabase   Dim doc As NotesDocument   Dim vue As NotesView   Dim ws As NotesUIWorkspace   Dim Masque As NotesUIDocument            Sub Initialize   Set Session = New NotesSession   Set curDb = Session.CurrentDatabase   Set ws = New NotesUIWorkspace   End Sub            UI.FieldGetText("titre")         Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)   Set Masque = Source   End Sub                        @Command([FileSave])               FIELD saveoptions:="0";   @Command([FileCloseWindow])                      @Command([FileSave])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you mixed two techniques of writing files here. You can completely omit the lines

```
f=Freefile
Open fichier For Output As #f
```

They belong to another type of writing files with print commands. Not needed here.

Second: did you check the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_WRITETEXT_METHOD_STREAM.html) for WriteText? Obviously not, because then you would have found the second (optional) parameter eol:

> bytes& = notesStream .WriteText( text$ , [ eol& ] )
>
> Parameter eol:
>   Constant of type Long. End-of-line character(s) appended to the text. **The default is EOL_NONE.**
>   - EOL_CR (2) appends a carriage return (ASCII 13).
>   - EOL_CRLF (0) appends a carriage return and line feed (ASCII 10 + 13).
>   - EOL_LF (1) appends a line feed (ASCII 10).
>   - EOL_NONE (5) appends nothing. Default.
>   - EOL_PLATFORM (3) follows the conventions of the current platform.

So one line of your code would be:

```
Call Stream.WriteText(|<datamodified>|, EOL_PLATFORM)
```

Or

```
Call Stream.WriteText(|<datamodified>|, EOL_CRLF)
```

Just add that second parameter for every line.